# Where to hook in wall broadcast for acpi/button triggered shutdown?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, shutdown

If someone/something shuts down the machine I am logged in to via ssh, I usually get just

```
Shared connection to 2001:db8::1 closed.
```

I would like to distinguish this from local or network issues:

```
Power button (/dev/input/..) pressed, shutting down now.
Critical battery action: shutting down now.
Immediate shutdown initiated by user betty, no wall message provided.
```

Where can I hook into systemd to enable a detailed broadcast while handling power buttons?

Partial solutions:

- A systemd unit hooked to run before sshd quits can report the ordinary shutdown procedure, but cannot reliably tell the *trigger* (`grep`ing for relevant *journal* entries works somewhat okay).
- When reasonably sure that a shutdown should not be attempted in the first place, I can use `systemd-inhitibit` instead, letting the other party figure out coordinating the shutdown with me.
- I know `wall` still works in modern times: `shutdown time "wall message"` *does* broadcast to all `mesg y` users. I could not find the place to enforce a default value.